# Uncountable family of pairwise disjoint discs/circles

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that there does not exist an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint discs in the
plane. What happens if we replace ‘discs’ by ‘circles’?

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried, and explain what's giving you trouble?

Comment: *Hint:* For circles, when are two concentric circles disjoint?

Comment: Theres a rational point in the disc and cant contain the same rational point, so i was hoping of an obvious injection to N

EDIT: an injection from the set of discs to the set of rational points (p,q)

Comment: There is an unattractive injection to $\mathbb{N}$. Enumerate the ordered pairs $(r,s)$ of rationals as $v_1,v_2,\dots$.  Map a disk to the smallest $i$ such that $v_i$ is in the disk.

Comment: Ah thank you and how would i find an injection from the set of discs to the set of rationals?

Comment: @user116498: That's what André just explained: well order the rational points, and map each disk to the first rational (according to the well order) that lies within it.

Comment: Thanks guys, not enjoying sets at the moment

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:** Every disk of non-zero radius contains a point with rational coordinates.

For circles, geometry will give you an easy uncountable collection.

Comment: Great hints IMO.

Comment: Ye thanks really helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The family of circles centered at a given point is an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint circles.